# How to search and extract certain values in cells - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following data, which can be seen by using the link below:

[Example of Input and desired Output Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jca78omwpdfp1hi/Total_Count_Example.xlsm)

**Using the following logic:**

> Extract all of JPM (arranger’s) total values from "Sheet1" and plot them in sheet 2, on each row under the column that says JPM.
>
> For example, if B1 in "Sheet2", is equals to BAML, then search BAML in sheet 1 and extract all its total values from column F and insert in "Sheet2", under the BAML column.
>
> Please NOTE: for example BAML can be in a cell by itself or it can be in any other position in a cell in column C.

I require help and assistant in developing a macro which can display the output as shown in the data link above, in "Sheet2". I am not sure, how would I go about solving this problem.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Kind regards

Input data (Sheet1)

[image]

Output data (Sheet2)
[image]

Comment: Why not attach a screenshot of your source data sheets here? Your link REQUIRES login credentials...

Comment: dear@bonCodigo, Thank you for your response, I do not have the permission to carry out the task of displaying screenshots, due to low level of reputation credit on my profile.  I apologize for the inconvenience, however i have updated the a new link for further reference. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: According to the Sheet 1 source, e.g. Row 6. You have price 500. There are three arrangers. So does it mean Total should be 500*3 and each arranger is contributing price 500? It is not clear how do you define price contributed by each arranger for multiple arranger records. Can you explain?

Comment: Thank you for your response @bonCodigo. In row 6, each arranger such as "CITG", "BAML" and "BCG", would contribute 500 price each, hence this is shown in the output.  So, each arranger in that row 6 of sheet 1 will have 500, same goes for the rows 7-13 (1812 price for all three arrangers in those rows). The position of the arrangers are never the same. Thank you your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the total of each cotributor, you can do it using following Excel formula. Change Criteria based on the contributor name, e.g. JPM, CITG, BAML... so on.

Formula:

```
=SUMIF($C$2:$C$13,"*JPM*",$B$2:$C$13)
```

Output

```
JPM      CITG    BAML    BCG     CIBC       DB
2432.74  500     500     500     1812.84    1812.84
```

Will this be sufficient for you?
Else do you want to show price for each contributor in a distributted pivot view?

**Since the OP's request is to sort prices by row for each contributor, a VBA snippet is coded.** For easier visual understanding the solution pivot is displayed next to your source data.

Following is the steps to solution and output.

1. Add a button to your Sheet.
2. Double click the button and add `Call splitSortPivot()`
3. Add a module to your Excel project
4. Double click on the module and copy the following code
5. Save, compile

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub splitSortPivot()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim i, j, k As Integer    
Dim sourceArray As Variant
Dim arrangersArray As Variant
Dim ary As Variant

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sourceRange = ws.Range("B2:C13")

'Based on the number of records +2 you have in source sheet (Sheet1)
'you may set the first dimension's upper bound of the array
'+1 for header and +1 for total --> in current case 12  + 1 + 1 = 14
'even setting this number can be done programmatically using used rows in C column.
ReDim arrangersArray(0 To 13, 5)

'This code can be optimized to add names programmatically
arrangersArray(0, 0) = "JPM"
arrangersArray(0, 1) = "CITG"
arrangersArray(0, 2) = "BAML"
arrangersArray(0, 3) = "BCG"
arrangersArray(0, 4) = "CIBC"
arrangersArray(0, 5) = "DB"

sourceArray = sourceRange.Value

    For j = LBound(sourceArray, 1) To UBound(sourceArray, 1)
        If InStr(1, sourceArray(j, 2), ",") > 0 Then
            ary = Split(sourceArray(j, 2), ",")
            For k = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
                For i = LBound(arrangersArray, 2) To UBound(arrangersArray, 2)
                    If arrangersArray(0, i) = Trim(ary(k)) Then 
                       arrangersArray(j, i) = sourceArray(j, 1)
                       arrangersArray(13, i) = arrangersArray(13, i) + arrangersArray(j, i)
                    End If
                Next i
            Next k
        Else
            For k = LBound(arrangersArray, 2) To UBound(arrangersArray, 2)
                If arrangersArray(0, k) = sourceArray(j, 2) Then
                    arrangersArray(j, k) = sourceArray(j, 1)
                    arrangersArray(13, k) = arrangersArray(13, k) + arrangersArray(j, k)
                End If
            Next k
        End If
    Next j

'Output the processed array into the Sheet. 
Range("G1").Resize(UBound(arrangersArray) + 1, _ 
UBound(Application.Transpose(arrangersArray))) = arrangersArray

End Sub
```

Output screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate your time. Is it possible to see prices for each arranger as well as the totals.  Thank you for your help in solving this problem.

Comment: In that case the most efficient would be to write a small vba snippet.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but would a macro be able to read the arranger's name in any position in cell? thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Yes a VBA macro can handle it. Please take a look at the updates. The VBA code will sort each row price for each contributor and finally give you the total. You may not need to use the Excel formula I provided earlier anymore. Please note that code is not 100% dynamic, as you will still have to specify Sheet name, data input, output ranges, number of rows used and so on. If you are interested in, that would be a good exercise for you get to know what this code is actually doing. Help you with future modifications to the code. :)