# Excel VBA: Copy cells from multiple sheets to a single sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new to VBA and am trying to automate a process at work where I need to extract select cells from an array of 6 sheets and consolidate them in another sheet. The code I have works, but is kinda "clunky" - I am using the excel copy and paste functions, but can't seem to find a good solution away from the copy-and-paste function. And when I try to add a paste special function, I get an 1004 error. Would love advice on optimising this!

For each sheet to be copied, cells are marked in the first column with "1", "0" or left blank - if the cells are "1" or "0", I copy the other cells in the row to the consolidated sheet. There are some gaps in between rows, so I opted to use a For-Loop instead of a Do-While statement.

I've attached the code as follows:

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim i As Integer 'copying row counter for each sheet to be copied
    Dim j As Integer 'pasting row counter in consolidated sheet
    Dim cal(1 To 6) As String  'copied sheetname
          cal(1) = "Picks"
          cal(2) = "Eats"
          cal(3) = "Night Out"
          cal(4) = "Active"
          cal(5) = "Family"
          cal(6) = "Arts"
    Dim x As Integer

    Dim y As Integer 'column for date
    Dim z As Integer 'max row to run till

    y = 1 'column checked in each sheet where condition for copying is met
    z = 300 'number of rows to check in each sheet

    j = 1

    For x = 1 To 6

    For i = 1 To z
        If Sheets(cal(x)).Cells(i, y) = "0" Or Sheets(cal(x)).Cells(i, y) = "1" Then
            Sheets(cal(x)).Select
            Range(Sheets(cal(x)).Cells(i, 2), Sheets(cal(x)).Cells(i, 10)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Consolidated).Cells(j, 1)
            ActiveSheet.Paste
    Else
        j = j - 1
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next i
    Next x
End Sub
```

Again I would love to optimise this code, using another method instead of copy-and-paste. Also I tried:

```
Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Consolidated).Cells(j, 1)
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Operation:=xlPasteValues
```

Which resulted in a 1004 error. Would love to know what went wrong.

Comment: Care enough to update your question with your expected output? :) If you can't update with a screen shot, please add a text view of the output. I assume you want to get the pivot/sub total kinda view in the final sheet. Is that correct?

Comment: If you ever want to keep away from copy paste and insted take those machine resources to achieve the results using more effective VBA snippet: Do a take a look at [some sample here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528333/how-to-search-and-extract-certain-values-in-cells-vba/13530138#13530138) The sample is not meant for your exact requirement. But to give you an idea of having more optimized perspective on your execution :)

Comment: @bonCodigo sorry for the late reply! I don't have enough reputation to post pictures. The input sheets have a set of formatting that I wish to change when I paste them in the output, how best could I do this? Would it be a pastespecial without formatting, then layering on the formatting somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because you're attempting to paste into the activesheet instead of into a range on the activesheet, and because you have the wrong argument for the `PasteSpecial` method.

This will work, although it's not what you want to do: (see `CopyWithoutClipboard` further below for a better alternative)

```
Sub PasteIntoGoto()
    Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
    Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Note the range inserted in between `ActiveSheet` and `PasteSpecial` and `Paste:=` instead of `Operation:=`.

You're right in wanting to optimize your code. Maybe the most important guideline in Excel VBA development is to **never select anything**, which can cause all kinds of problems. In your first example, you are using `.Select` explicitly, and in the second example, `.GoTo` is effectively doing the same thing.

Rather than selecting a sheet, copying a range, selecting another sheet, and pasting into another range, you can write a copy of the data to the target range (either on the same sheet or on another one) like this:

```
Sub CopyWithoutClipboard()
    Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Copy Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Obviously you can use variables in place of the hard-coded objects in the snippet above.

Comment: +1 for "never select anything". That's a taboo if you expect optimization :D Also try to keep your programme calc manual while processing and then put back in auto calc once all completed.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! @headofcatering I tried: _Sheets(cal(x)).Range(Cells(i, 15), Cells(i, 26)).Copy Sheets(goba).Range(Cells(j + 1, 1), Cells(j + 1, 12))_ but that didn't seem to work. Why so? It did work with _Range(Sheets(cal(x)).Cells(i, 15), Sheets(cal(x)).Cells(i, 26)).Copy Sheets(goba).Cells(j + 1, 1)_

Comment: @bonCodigo apologies for the ignorance, but what do you mean by auto-calc?