# extract employee id by matching name and email address

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets-Sheet1 has Last name,First name in one column and email address in one column.
Sheet2 also has Last name, First name in one column, email address in one column and Employee id in another.

I want a macro to match names from sheet 1 with two columns - Last name, First name and also email address if both match than i wanted to extract Employee id and write adjacent to that name on Sheet 1

Thanks
Puneet

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a free coding service. It's a help site - show us what you've tried yourself and we will offer advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search and extract certain values in cells - VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528333/how-to-search-and-extract-certain-values-in-cells-vba)

Answer (score 1):

You can use MATCH() and INDEX() for this.  Make sure to enter the formula using Ctrl+Shift+Enter

[image]